# What rig or rigs are onboard the ISS?

Tags: equipment

[This article](http://www.businessinsider.com/social-network-ham-radio-2014-5) mentions the Ham Shack aboard the ISS. From the picture it looks like a small very light rig like a Yaesu FT-817. What radio(s) do the astronauts use when they talk to Hams and School-age kids (with help from licensed hams) on earth?

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia and ISSFANCLUB, in 2011, they had a Kenwood TM-D700 UHF/VHF rig, and also an Ericcson UHF/VHF rig.  When the Kenwood had problems, they switched for a while to the Ericcson backup unit.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_Radio_on_the_International_Space_Station

http://issfanclub.com/node/35931

Answer (score 3):

The official ARISS web site [documents the current equipment](http://www.ariss.org/contact-the-iss.html) as follows (scroll down for the headline **Radios, Modes and Antennas on the ISS**):

> The ISS amateur radios are Ericsson MP-X handheld radios, a Kenwood TM
>   D700 and a Kenwood D710.

The crew is currently able to use these radios to operate on the 2 m and 70 cm bands. Voice, packet radio and SSTV are the operational modes.

There is also a brand new "Ham Video" DVB-S digital television transmitter for the 2.4 GHz amateur radio band. The transmitter is being taken into use right now (July 2014) according the [news page of the official site](http://www.ariss.org/news.html).

Comment: This is more up to date than the ISSFANCLUB and Wikipedia info!

Comment: Yes, it seems like the ARISS web site has received a facelift and a lot of new information since my last visit!